# Assign AD roles using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, roles, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to assign User Administrator AD role to Azure Function App managed Identity through Azure DevOps YAML pipeline using AzurePowerShell@5 task.
Here is what I tried, but it gives me: ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $functionAppDeltaSyncName,
    $logicAppName_d365hrpublisher,
    $logicAppName_d365hrsubscriber,
    $resourceGroupName
)

Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview -Force

$appArray = $functionAppDeltaSyncName, $logicAppName_d365hrpublisher, $logicAppName_d365hrsubscriber

$aadAccessToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceTypeName AadGraph
$context = Get-AzContext
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadAccessToken.Token -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id

For ($x=0; $x -lt $appArray.Length; $x++)
{
    $managedIdentityObjectId = (Get-AzFunctionApp -Name $appArray[$x] -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).IdentityPrincipalId


    $roleUserAdministrator = Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq 'User Administrator'"

    $IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator = Get-AzureADMSRoleAssignment -Id $managedIdentityObjectId |
        Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionId -eq $roleUserAdministrator.Id }

    if ($null -eq $IsAppRoleAssigned) {
        New-AzureADMSRoleAssignment `
            -DirectoryScopeId '/' `
            -RoleDefinitionId $IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator.Id `
            -PrincipalId $managedIdentityObjectId
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have provided check  the " if condition" >   `if ($null -eq $IsAppRoleAssigned)`

powershell:

```
  $IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator = Get-AzureADMSRoleAssignment -Filter "principalId eq '$managedIdentityObjectId' " |
        Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionId -eq $aadDirectoryRole.Id }

    if ($null -eq $IsAppRoleAssigned) {
        New-AzureADMSRoleAssignment `
            -DirectoryScopeId '/' 
            -RoleDefinitionId   `
            -PrincipalId $managedIdentityObjectId
    }
```

where `$IsAppRoleAssigned` is declared nowhere , but **`$IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator`** is the declared variable.

It can be corrected it to resolve the error almost.

Also when      `$IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator` is **null** and has no value `$IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator.RoleDefinitionId` does not contain any value, in that scenario following command does not work as RoleDefinitionId will be null.

[image]

That is where you might have got “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”:

Check the correct code

Instead get role definitionId of User Administrator using below command (`$roledefId_UserAdmin`
) to assign while creating new role assignment in if condition.

```
    $functionApp = Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $functionApp
       
 $functionApp.IdentityPrincipalId
        
        $managedIdentityObjectId=$functionApp.IdentityPrincipalId
        
Write-host “function App principal id is fetched"
  
  $roleUserAdministrator=Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq 'User Administrator'" 
  
  $roledefId_UserAdmin=Get-AzureADMSRoleAssignment  |Where-Object { 
$_.RoleDefinitionId -eq $aadDirectoryRole.Id } 
    
     
   $IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator = Get-AzureADMSRoleAssignment -Filter "principalId eq '$managedIdentityObjectId' " |
      Where-Object { $_.RoleDefinitionId -eq $roleUserAdministrator.Id }
    
        if ($IsAppRoleAssigned_UserAdministrator -eq $null   ) {
            New-AzureADMSRoleAssignment `
                -DirectoryScopeId '/' `
                -RoleDefinitionId '$roledefId_UserAdmin.RoleDefinitionId'`
                -PrincipalId '$managedIdentityObjectId'`
        }
```

Check if the role is assigned to the service principal:

[image]
**`Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember  -ObjectId “942fxxx-xxx699449b8”`**

Here ObjectId is the objectId  of the Role “User Administrator”

[image]

Reference : [Get-AzureADMSRoleAssignment (AzureAD) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadmsroleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0)

Comment: When I deploy it using Azure DevOpe Pipeline I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object for     $roleUserAdministrator = Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq 'User Administrator'"

Comment: Have you tried to run this command separatly to check if its giving any result: `Get-AzureADMSRoleDefinition -Filter "displayName eq 'User Administrator'"`